# How to make Dynamic checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

WHAT I WANT :   I have 2 Different Tables and one have all categories ID and second one is places belong to these category now  when i make edit option for the places and i want to show all category so if user want to add a new and also i want to show already chooses cat as checked checkbox.

WHAT I TRY : here is my code

```
<?php $sql1="SELECT * FROM `app_category` ";
         // var_dump($sql);
          $check1= mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
          $resultcheck1= mysqli_fetch_array($check1,MYSQLI_BOTH);

                      foreach($check1 as $row){?>

                       <div class="checkbox-inline">
                           <span style="margin-left:10px"></span><input name="chk[]" value="<?php echo $row['cat_id'];?>" type="checkbox" id="checky"><span><?php echo $row['category_name'];?> </span><span style="margin-left:10px"></span>
                      </div>

                      <?php } ?>
                       <br>

                  </div>
```

here am fetching data from all categories and showing it on from now  have second table having cat id as forign key and i want to check if the cat exist in second table it marked as a check :
so i tried a logic :

```
<?php $sql11="SELECT cat_id FROM `app_placesmain` ";
         // var_dump($sql);
          $checkplace= mysqli_query($conn, $sql11);
          $resultcheck11= mysqli_fetch_array($checkplace,MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

i saved it to another array and now i want to check if the app_placemain have that category it marked as checked in checkbox i try array_diff ,if else etc etc but fail please help me out thanks in advance

i tried this now but still get all box checked here is my code :

```
<?php $sql1="SELECT * FROM `app_category` ";
         // var_dump($sql);
          $check1= mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
          $resultcheck1= mysqli_fetch_array($check1,MYSQLI_BOTH);

 $sql1="SELECT * FROM `app_placesmain` ";
         // var_dump($sql);
          $check11= mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
          $autocheck_array= mysqli_fetch_array($check11,MYSQLI_BOTH);


                      foreach($check1 as $row){$id=$row['cat_id'];?>

                       <div class="checkbox-inline">
                           <span style="margin-left:10px"></span><input name="chk[]" value="' 
. $id . '"' . (in_array($id, $autocheck_array) ? ' checked="checked"' : '')" type="checkbox" id="checky"><span><?php echo $row['category_name'];?> </span><span style="margin-left:10px"></span>
                      </div>

                      <?php } ?>
```

[image: here is my result screen]

Still Fail :

```
<lable><b>Categories</b></lable><br>
                      <?php $sql1="SELECT * FROM `app_category` ";
         // var_dump($sql);
          $check1= mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
          $resultcheck1= mysqli_fetch_array($check1,MYSQLI_BOTH);

 $sql11="SELECT * FROM `app_placesmain` ";
         // var_dump($sql);
          $check11= mysqli_query($conn, $sql11);
          $autocheck_array= mysqli_fetch_array($check11,MYSQLI_BOTH);


                      foreach($check1 as $row){ $id=$row['cat_id']; ?>

                       <div class="checkbox-inline">
                           <span style="margin-left:10px"></span><input name="chk[]" value="<?php echo  
'. $id . ' . (in_array($id, $autocheck_array) ? ' checked=checked' : '')?>" type="checkbox" id="checky"><span><?php echo $row['category_name'];?> </span><span style="margin-left:10px"></span>
                      </div>

                      <?php } ?>
                       <br>

                  </div>
```

NOW I HAVE USED THIS LOGIC BUT SOMETHING I MISS AND IT DID'T WORK HELP ME OUT :

```
<lable><b>Categories</b></lable><br>
                      <?php $sql1="SELECT * FROM `app_category` ";
         // var_dump($sql);
          $check1= mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
          $resultcheck1= mysqli_fetch_array($check1,MYSQLI_BOTH);

 $sql11="SELECT cat_id FROM `app_placesmain` ";
         // var_dump($sql);
          $check11= mysqli_query($conn, $sql11);
          $autocheck_array= mysqli_fetch_array($check11,MYSQLI_BOTH);


                      foreach($check1 as $row){ $id=$row['cat_id'];  

                      while($autocheck_array=mysqli_fetch_array($check11,MYSQLI_BOTH)){
                      ?>

                       <div class="checkbox-inline">
                           <span style="margin-left:10px"></span><input name="chk[]" value="<?php echo  
'. $id . ' . (in_array($id, $autocheck_array) ? ' checked="checked"' : '')?>" type="checkbox" id="checky"><span><?php echo $row['category_name'];?> </span><span style="margin-left:10px"></span>
                      </div>

                      <?php }} ?>
                       <br>
                      AT LAST GOT SOLUTION MY OWN THANKS FOR YOUR HELP :

<lable><b>Categories</b></lable><br>
                      <?php $sql1="SELECT * FROM `app_category` ";
         // var_dump($sql);
          $check1= mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
          $resultcheck1= mysqli_fetch_array($check1,MYSQLI_BOTH);

 $sql11="SELECT * FROM `app_places`";
         // var_dump($sql);
          $check11= mysqli_query($conn, $sql11);
          $autocheck= mysqli_fetch_array($check11,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
//var_dump($autocheck);
//exit();

                      foreach($check1 as $row){   


                      ?>

                       <div class="checkbox-inline">
                           <span style="margin-left:10px"></span><input name="chk[]" value="<?php echo $row['cat_id'];?>" type="checkbox" id="checky" <?php foreach($check11 as $row1) { if ($row['cat_id']==$row1['cat_id']) echo 'checked="checked"'; }?> ><span><?php echo $row['category_name'];?> </span><span style="margin-left:10px"></span>
                      </div>

                      <?php }?>
```

Comment: Add more information on how you failed, add errors, expected/unexpected outputs.

Comment: when i try array diff it shows 0 elemnts in array ...and now i try in array having this code : value="' 
. $id . '"' . (in_array($id, $autocheck_array) ? ' checked="checked"' : '')"

Comment: While `$autocheck_array` is an array, it 1 row from your table, not an array of all the `cat_id`s. Also, you placed php code in the html, not inside php tags.

Comment: i have change the code but when i use while loop it goes in infinite loop please suggest some code